# VennDiagram - internal labels

Tags: r, venn-diagram

[image]I plotted my genelists using the VennDiagram R package, and the diagram looks fine.

I wanted to add internal labels to the Venn diagram like, if data is shared by first and second group but not by the third and fourth group, then the label should be 1100. I found one thing on Venn{gplots} package which uses the `showSetLogicLabel=TRUE` to do this.

I am searching exactly for the same functionality, but using the VennDiagram package.

Exactly, like in the below picture, which gives binary codes to every count in the diagram. 
I wanted to generate that binary codes in the VennDiagram package.

http://rgm2.lab.nig.ac.jp/RGM_results/gplots:venn/venn_016_big.png

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've made some edits to you question to hopefully make it clearer.

Comment: @user1732190 Would you please add some example code? It would greatly help

Comment: venn.diagram(list(A=a1,B=a2,C=a3,D=a4),
            filename="all_interactions.tiff",
            category = c("x5x9","x6x10","x5x6","x9x10"),
            lwd = c(0.5:4),
            fill=c("blue","red","green","pink"),
            cex=2,
            cat.cex = 2,
            cat.dist = 0.09,
            ext.pos = 30,
            ext.dist = -0.05,
            ext.length = 0.85,
            ext.line.lwd = 2,
            ext.line.lty = "dashed",
            main="X[i]>10 and qvalue<=0.01",
            main.cex=1,
            main.col="grey")

Comment: When you get above 10 rep (http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/new-user), you can add images. In the editing box, there are icons to make this easier and more extensive help available.

Comment: I added the example code from the comment into the question itself. It is not self contained (since `a1`, `a2`, `a3`, and `a4` are not defined), though.

Comment: @user1732190, better question now, but why don't you register a better user id?

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
library(VennDiagram)
draw.triple.venn(65, 75, 85, 35, 15, 25, 5, c("First", "Second", "Third"))
```

[image: 3 Groups Venn Diagram]

Or this for a nicer view, and 4 groups:

```
A <- sample(1:1000, 400, replace = FALSE); 
B <- sample(1:1000, 600, replace = FALSE);
C <- sample(1:1000, 350, replace = FALSE);
D <- sample(1:1000, 550, replace = FALSE);
E <- sample(1:1000, 375, replace = FALSE);
venn.diagram(x = list(A = A,D = D,B = B,C = C), filename = "Venn.tiff",
col = "transparent", fill = c("cornflowerblue","green","yellow","darkorchid1"),
alpha = 0.50, label.col = c("orange", "white", "darkorchid4", "white", "white", 
"white",    "white", "white", "darkblue", "white", "white", "white", "white", 
"darkgreen", "white"), cex = 1.5, fontfamily = "serif", fontface = "bold",
cat.col = c("darkblue", "darkgreen", "orange", "darkorchid4"), cat.cex = 1.5,
cat.pos = 0, cat.dist = 0.07, cat.fontfamily = "serif", rotation.degree = 270,
margin = 0.2)
```

[image: 4 Groups Venn Diagram]

There are plenty of more examples in the VennDiagram Document ([Here](http://www.stats.bris.ac.uk/R/web/packages/VennDiagram/VennDiagram.pdf))

Comment: this doesn't answer the OP's question -- they wanted labels based on binary occupancy codes, not numbers of occupants

Comment: http://rgm2.lab.nig.ac.jp/RGM_results/gplots:venn/venn_016_big.png   Like in the picture, I want some thing like that kind of binary codes in my venn diagram

Comment: @user1732190: OK, let's see if I can do something or not

Comment: @user1732190 I tried to use the return value of the function to extract x, y dimensions of the texts. It was successful. However using a text() function to put the new labels on the diagram manually fails. Also it's not trivial to find out the groups from the text labels or positions.

Comment: @user1732190 Finally I think the best option is to use Venn(gplots)

Comment: I was looking for the `cat.cex`, i thought it would be true, but seeing it here did the job for me.  Thanks.