# Adding extra texts to a venn diagram drawn using VennDiagram R package

Tags: r, venn-diagram

I have a code taken from the package VennDiagram for drawing a venn diagram (below). I'm able to implement this code to draw a venn diagram, but I would also like to add extra text to each of the partitioned areas (unique and common to I, II, II, IV). For example, after running this code, the unique section 'I' is 60, I will like to add something like XX XU at the bottom of 60, and so on for the other partitioned areas as well. Is there a way in R to modify this code to achieve these changes?

```
library(VennDiagram)

venn.plot <- venn.diagram(
   x = list(
       I = c(1:60, 61:105, 106:140, 141:160, 166:175, 176:180, 181:205, 206:220),
       IV = c(531:605, 476:530, 336:375, 376:405, 181:205, 206:220, 166:175, 176:180),
       II = c(61:105, 106:140, 181:205, 206:220, 221:285, 286:335, 336:375, 376:405),
       III = c(406:475, 286:335, 106:140, 141:160, 166:175, 181:205, 336:375, 476:530)
       ),
filename = "1D-quadruple_Venn.tiff",
col = "black",
lty = "dotted",
lwd = 4,
fill = c("cornflowerblue", "green", "yellow", "darkorchid1"),
alpha = 0.50,
label.col = c("orange", "white", "darkorchid4", "white", "white", "white",
 "white", "white", "darkblue", "white",
  "white", "white", "white", "darkgreen", "white"),
cex = 2.5,
fontfamily = "serif",
fontface = "bold",
cat.col = c("darkblue", "darkgreen", "orange", "darkorchid4"),
cat.cex = 2.5,
cat.fontfamily = "serif"
);
```

venn digrams:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Not clear what do you want to achieve. better to add a plot to your question and add the text by hand(using paint or other tools) to the plot to clarify what do you want to do.

Comment: I don't think this is (easily) possible. See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12803390/venndiagram-internal-labels - although it was a while ago. That said you could manually change the grob labels.

Answer (score 2):

Something to help you start:

I used your example, but for `filename` I used `NULL`, because I wanted to plot the venn diagram along with extra labels.

```
## Function that creates a grid.text object
## The offset sets the distance from existing label 
addlab <- function(lab, x, y, offset = 0) {
    grid.text(lab, unit(as.numeric(x), "npc"), 
                   unit(as.numeric(y) - offset, "npc"), 
              draw = FALSE)
}

## Adding a number under each label
lbls <- gList()
o <- 1 ## counter
for(i in seq(along.with=venn.plot)) {
  ## Check if it is a grid.text object
  if(regexpr("text", venn.plot[[i]]$name) > 0) {
    ## Write counter value under the existing label
    lbls <- gList(lbls, addlab(o, venn.plot[[i]]$x, venn.plot[[i]]$y, 0.03))
    ## Increase the counter
    o <- o + 1
  }
}
```

Plot the Venn diagram and the labels:

```
## tiff("out.tiff")
grid.draw(venn.plot)
grid.draw(lbls)
## dev.off()
```

[image]

From the numbers you can see the order you have to put your labels to achieve what you want.

Hope this will help you,

alex

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex for the codes to start me off in the right direction. I appreciate your help. I'm now working to get the codes to write two numbers under each label.